# Angular why doesn't work nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use nested `ng-repeat` to loop in all objects values.

```
    <tr class="" ng-repeat="(position, values) in chartResult.realData track  by $index">
      <td>
          <div ng-click="select(position)" ng-class="{selected: position===selectedItem}">
              <a href ng-click="select(position)">
                <span>{{position}}</span>
              </a>
          </div>
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="val in values">
           {{val}}
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Why nested loop doesn't work?

**Updated**

```
app.controller('Ctrl',['$log', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$timeout',
  function ($log, $rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout) {

$http({
      //request
    }).then(
      function successCallback(response) {

//after parse response realData view something like this
var res = {realData:
            name1:[1,2,4,0,1,23],
            name2:[4,6,3,7,2,3],
            ...
          }
$scope.chartResult = res;
}

}]);
```

Comment: Please add your controller with the data your are trying to render with `ng-repeat`.

Comment: are you sure `values` contains information?

Comment: Yes the data from {{position}} render as well. And if use {{values}} under {{position}} it shows array with data. <span>{{position}} {{values}}</span>

Comment: Can we see some data from the chartResult.realData?

Comment: do you want to add a jsbin or pluinkr, maybe?

Comment: updated with controller

Answer (score 0):

After add `track by $index` to nested loop it work as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you pasted it correctly realData is not an array.

But please show us what is in the realData.